# Install tikz-cd

Tags: installing

How to install tikz-cd, I am using texshop. I need the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{
  commutative diagrams/.cd,
  arrow style=tikz,
  diagrams={>=space}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
               & A \arrow{d}            &              \\
               & B \arrow{dl}\arrow{dr} &              \\
  C \arrow{dr} &                        & D \arrow{dl} \\
               & F                      &              \\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Or alternatively, could we write in a different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using TeXshop, then you most probably are working with the MacTeX distribution.

First make sure that you have the current version (2012). If not, download the installer from [the MacTeX homepage](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2012/).

Then run the TeX Live Utility (via Applications -> TeX -> TeX Live Utility) to make sure that all packages are up to date, including `tikz-cd`.